# laravel- artisal key erro ao tentar gerar

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

puxei um exemplo de um projeto de laravel e quando tendo dar um `php artisan generat:key` ele me volta o seguinte erro

```
 [Dotenv\Exception\InvalidFileException]
  Dotenv values containing spaces must be surrounded by quotes.
```

.env:

```
APP_NAME=Webchat ADMIN
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=webchat_admin
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=redis
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O comando está escrito de forma errada, a forma correta é a seguinte:

```
 php artisan key:generate
```

Como está descrito [aqui](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/installation) na instalação do *Laravel*.

Outra coisa que pode estar acontecendo é que no seu arquivo `.env` existem espaços em alguma palavra, como por exemplo.

```
VAR=algum texto
```

Palavras com espaço devem estar dentro de Aspas

```
VAR="algum texto"
```